# Is the space of monotone real sequences from $[0,1]$ connected?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

It is a consequence of a well-known theorem from general topology that the vector space $[0,1]^\mathbb{N}$ of real sequences with values in the interval $[0,1]$ together with product topology is connected. Consider the (topological) subspace consisting of all **monotone** sequences with values in $[0,1].$ Is this space connected ?

Comment: Do you consider $x_n=0$ monotone? Or do you mean "strictly monotone"?

Answer (score 6):

If you explicitely meant *monotone* (and not strictly monotone), then the space is connected, because any sequence $x_n$ is directly connected to the zero-sequence $0_n$ via

$$\gamma(t)=tx_n,\quad t\in[0,1].$$

So the set is star-shaped, hence connected.

---

However, if you meant *strictly monotone*, then the set is *not* connected as there is no path between an increasing sequence and a decreasing one.

Any path $\gamma$ between such sequences starts with $\gamma(0)_1<\gamma(0)_2$ and ends with $\gamma(1)_1>\gamma(1)_2$ (the sub-indices indicate the elements of the sequence). Because of (point-wise) continuity and the intermediate value theorem it must pass some $t$ with $\gamma(t)_1=\gamma(t)_2$. But this sequence $\gamma(t)$ is not strictly monotone, hence not in your space.

Note that the subspace of strictly increasing/decreasing sequences is convex, therefore connected.  This means that the space of strictly monotone sequences has exactly two connected components.